# Why do some paperbacks have shortened front covers?

Tags: physical-books

Some paperback editions have a front cover which is a centimetre or two shorter than the actual book. I first noticed this on *House of Leaves*, where I thought that it's just part of the whole experimental deal (representing the house whose inside is larger than the outside, and/or just putting the book firmly into uncanny valley), but since then I've seen a couple of other books which do this, like this paperback edition of Ken Liu's *The Paper Menagerie*:

[image: House of Leaves and The Paper Menagerie paperbacks]

So I'm assuming this is actually a thing that is done for some books, and googling confirms that. However, I haven't found any good sources on *why* this is done.

Comment: As a side note, any bibliophile needs a copy of that Ken Liu paperback, just because of how amazing the texture of the cover is. :)

Comment: It is fundamentally an artistic choice, but I am wondering whether that sort of answer actually answers what you're asking for. Do you also mean to be asking what _about_ the text prompts that choice?

Comment: @Zyerah If it's really a purely artistic choice, the reason *why* someone might make that choice would definitely be interesting. The reasoning from House of Leaves doesn't generally apply to other books.

Comment: @Zyerah if it's fundamentally an artistic choice, then that's answer, even if that choice has nothing to do with the text of the book.

Comment: Maybe it's for a better grip when opening the book? You can open the front cover easier if it is not the same size as the actual pages as it 'separates' it. Hardcover book covers are generally easier to open as they are very thick and the cover usually overlaps over the actual pages, but normal paperbacks don't. So the paperbacks with shortened covers combat this. My thoughts only, I don't have any evidence so I don't know whether I can make this an answer.

Comment: The technical term is a "stepback cover". Other examples include those with centre cut-outs (to make windows) and romance novels with a second interior-double-spread.

Comment: If you google "stepback cover" you'll find various discussions, but no explanation other than "it looks cool" or "it's a fad".

Answer (score -2):

I was told by a bookseller that these were books that had not sold and were “remaindered” by trimming the front cover. This prevents them from being resold at their full value.

Comment: The books presented in the question were *initially made* this way, though, not mutilated after production

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can remember buying discount bin paperbacks like this from WH Smith in the 80s and I was also told this was prevent full price sale.